# Invalid symbol: "default"

Tags: xamarin.android

My Android project in Xamarin keeps failing to build due to below error

invalid symbol :"default" default.png res/drawable/default.png

not sure what is causing this to happen.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Ravi

Comment: default is a c# reserved word

Answer (score 5):

[default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/default) is c# keyword, you need rename your picture's name.

Comment: Thanks!  Had the same issue with case.png.  Probably should be handled better by the compiler, but at least can avoid that, now.  The error message was not very helpful either.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned before default is the keywords and that why it's failing . I wanted to share the lists so you  may save your time by not using other keyword .  We have quite a large number of keywords in c#:
Please find the few list mentioned in link below:
http://azuliadesigns.com/list-keywords-reserved-words/
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x53a06bb(v=vs.120).aspx

http://www.dotnetfunda.com/codes/show/945/list-of-csharp-reserved-keyword
So if u use any of the reserved names u may come across this kind of error.